# React - Call method of a routed rendered component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How to call a method inside the Dashboard Component, since ref="id" cannot be applied in this instance:

```
<Route
  path='/dashboard'
  render={(props) => <Dashboard {...props} isAuthed={true} />}
/>
```

Context:
I have a service running in the AppComponent. When service finishes running, I want to update a list in the ChildComponent. There are more the one ChildComponent, so I can navigate through the children while the service keeps running in AppComponent. So whatever child(route) I am, the list will be updated after the service finishes. So, I need to update this list in the child component, which is routed.

Comment: Could you provide a little more context? Usually you do not imperatively call functions on components with react. There are very few use cases where this is required. Instead you pass a callback as a prop that can then be called by the child.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve it by passing a prop where the child can send its class to the parent.

PARENT

```
<Route
  path='/dashboard'
  render={(props) => <Dashboard {...props} setChild={this.setChild} />}
/>

setChild = (component) =>{
    this.childComponent = component
  }
```

ROUTED CHILDREN

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    props.setChild(this);
  }
```

Then I can call any method in routed child component by calling.

PARENT

```
this.childComponent.childMethod();
```